# Dynamically generate Application.properties file in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

I have came across a situation where I need to fetch cron expression from database and then schedule it in Spring boot. I am fetching the data using JPA. Now the problem is in spring boot when I use `@Scheduled` annotation it does not allow me to use the db value directly as it is taken only constant value. So, what I am planning to do is to dynamically generate properties file and read cron expression from properties file. But here also I am facing one problem.The dynamically generated properties file created in target directory.
So I cant use it the time of program loading.
So can anyone assist me to read the dynamically generated file from the resource folder or how to schedule cron expression fetching from DB in spring boot?

If I placed all the details of corn expression in properties file I can schedule the job. 
Latest try with dynamically generate properties file.

```
    @Configuration
    public class CronConfiguration {

        @Autowired
        private JobRepository jobRepository;

        @Autowired
        private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

        @PostConstruct
        protected void initialize() {
            updateConfiguration();
        }

        private void updateConfiguration() {
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            List<Job> morningJobList=new ArrayList<Job>();
            List<String> morningJobCornExp=new ArrayList<String>();
           // Map<String,String> map=new HashMap<>();
            int num=1;
            System.out.println("started");
           morningJobList= jobRepository.findByDescriptionContaining("Morning Job");
           for(Job job:morningJobList) {
               //morningJobURL.add(job.getJobUrl());
               morningJobCornExp.add(job.getCronExp());
           }
           for(String cron:morningJobCornExp ) {
               properties.setProperty("cron.expression"+num+"=", cron);
               num++;
           }       

            Resource propertiesResource = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:application1.properties");
            try (OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(propertiesResource.getFile()))) {
                properties.store(out, null);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                // Handle error
                ex.printStackTrace();

            }
        }   
}

Still it is not able to write in properties file under resource folder.
```

Comment: It does allow an expression. The `cron` can take an SpEL or Value expression. You are making things more complex than necessary. If that doesn't work just use a bean that loads the expression and manually schedule it with the `TaskScheduler`. Don't make it more complex than necessary.

Comment: I have tried with @Bean annotation as well. It will work but getting multiple values from database will not work .Only the last value getting reflected.

Comment: @Bean
     @Scheduled(cron = "30 57 13 ? * *") public String getCronExp() {
          morningJobList= jobRepository.findByDescriptionContaining("Morning Job"); for(Job job:morningJobList) {           morningJobCornExp.add(job.getCronExp());}                                                                                                                                      for(String s:morningJobCornExp) {
           cronExp=s;}return cornExp;                                                                                                                then @Scheduled(cron="#{@getCronExp}")

Comment: Don't define the expressions as beans that won't work and generally defining simple things like String and int as beans is the wrong thing to do. As stated create a bean that manually registeres the schedule with the `TaskExecutor` instead of trying to shoehorn something else into it. Another solution would be to make a database driven property-source so that it will retrieve properties from the database.

Comment: I am trying to create a dynamically generated properties file from database but the file was created inside a target directory. Problem is that when spring boot try to find the properties at the load time it will not find the dynamically generated file.

Comment: Again don't create a properties file. Create a bean, that loads the schedules from DB, and manually schedule the tasks... Or create a `PropertySource` that is backed by the database, so that it is part of the general environment and you can use it to resolve expressions. Forget the manual creation .

Comment: do you have any leads so that it can help me?

Comment: I already explained what you need to do. Create a bean, that retrieves the schedules and manually schedule the tasks with the `TaskExecutor`... That basically is psuedo code of what you need to do.

Comment: Thing is that I have multiple corn expressions which need to be scheduled. For one it is possible.Please share some code snippet so that it can help me.

Comment: I already gave you the approach in psuedo code. The only thing you need to do is implement that.

Answer (score -1):

Consider using [Quartz Scheduler](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) framework. It stores scheduler info in DB. No need to implement own DB communication, it is already provided.

Found this example: https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-quartz-scheduler-email-scheduling-example/